# Laravel "This webpage has a redirect loop" only on a single route suddenly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, redirect-loop

Ok so the thing is I have laravel 4.2 installed and it's working great.

Up to today when I did a couple of small changes and now my website/used path returns this incredibly infuriating message "This webpage has a redirect loop" forever and ever.
I am using localisation and the mcamara plugin installed, up until today all was perfect and I could use my 2 locals en/da without any problems like website/en/used or website/da/used and of course the normal paths website/used etc which would remember lang choice and show content as such.

Now after trying to implement a simple feature: Creating a UsedController to handler form requests for a new view which should make it possible to upload a picture and title and description. It worked for a couple of tries without posting to database, just dd, then suddenly this issue with redirect starts and now 6 hours or so on it keeps going on and on and on and it's making me totally frustrated, I deleted everything I created and now it still won't work at all.

website/en/used and website/da/used still works though, but website/used gets the page from hell every time :(

So my question I guess is:
Why can a controller just "hijack" a route like that, and also just refuse to do it's job?

currently only when accessed website/used I get the loop error, index @ used does nothing despite trying to move the view there.

here is my routes.php file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrapO.jpg

here are the routes:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7xRN.png

Still don't get why a controller here being "UsedController" now suddenly hijacks all /used
and according to this routes table, my requests to /used should go through UsedController@index yes? But weirdly this doesn't happen :( it completely ignores everything and all I get atm is this endless loop thing.

After even further testing and editing I even cleared the entire routes file only to have UsedController left like this:
Route::resource('used', 'UsedController');
even that still won't work when I tried that and just tried displaying the view with index function at UsedController.

Investigating it in chrome has the following:

```
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961301.056,"children":         [{"type":"ResourceSendRequest","data":    {"requestId":"1172.166","url":"westcoastmink.dev:8888/used/","requestMethod":"GET"},"startTime":13961301.449,"frameId":"1172.1"}],"endTime":13961301.546},
```

{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961301.957,"children":[],"endTime":13961301.989},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961306.072,"children":[],"endTime":13961306.103},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961306.133,"children":[{"type":"ResourceSendRequest","data":{"requestId":"1172.166","url":"westcoastmink.dev:8888/used","requestMethod":"GET"},"startTime":13961306.339,"frameId":"1172.1"}],"endTime":13961306.402},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961309.474,"children":[],"endTime":13961309.507},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961309.539,"children":[{"type":"ResourceSendRequest","data":{"requestId":"1172.166","url":"westcoastmink.dev:8888/used/","requestMethod":"GET"},"startTime":13961309.776,"frameId":"1172.1"}],"endTime":13961309.908},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961312.76,"children":[],"endTime":13961312.811},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961317.462,"children":[],"endTime":13961317.505},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961317.555,"children":[{"type":"ResourceSendRequest","data":{"requestId":"1172.166","url":"westcoastmink.dev:8888/used","requestMethod":"GET"},"startTime":13961317.899,"frameId":"1172.1"}],"endTime":13961318.027},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961325.426,"children":[],"endTime":13961325.469},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961325.539,"children":[{"type":"ResourceSendRequest","data":{"requestId":"1172.166","url":"westcoastmink.dev:8888/used/","requestMethod":"GET"},"startTime":13961326.142,"frameId":"1172.1"}],"endTime":13961326.299},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961329.605,"children":[],"endTime":13961329.634},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961329.664,"children":[{"type":"ResourceSendRequest","data":{"requestId":"1172.166","url":"westcoastmink.dev:8888/used","requestMethod":"GET"},"startTime":13961329.964,"frameId":"1172.1"}],"endTime":13961330.057},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961333.556,"children":[],"endTime":13961333.585},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961333.619,"children":[{"type":"ResourceSendRequest","data":{"requestId":"1172.166","url":"westcoastmink.dev:8888/used/","requestMethod":"GET"},"startTime":13961334.033,"frameId":"1172.1"}],"endTime":13961334.201},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961341.465,"children":[],"endTime":13961341.521},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961341.586,"children":[{"type":"ResourceSendRequest","data":{"requestId":"1172.166","url":"westcoastmink.dev:8888/used","requestMethod":"GET"},"startTime":13961341.946,"frameId":"1172.1"}],"endTime":13961342.057},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961348.486,"children":[],"endTime":13961348.518},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961348.553,"children":[{"type":"ResourceSendRequest","data":{"requestId":"1172.166","url":"westcoastmink.dev:8888/used/","requestMethod":"GET"},"startTime":13961348.829,"frameId":"1172.1"}],"endTime":13961348.902},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961353.626,"children":[],"endTime":13961353.655},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961353.687,"children":[{"type":"ResourceSendRequest","data":{"requestId":"1172.166","url":"westcoastmink.dev:8888/used","requestMethod":"GET"},"startTime":13961353.908,"frameId":"1172.1"}],"endTime":13961353.985},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961359.02,"children":[],"endTime":13961359.05},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961359.076,"children":[{"type":"ResourceSendRequest","data":{"requestId":"1172.166","url":"westcoastmink.dev:8888/used/","requestMethod":"GET"},"startTime":13961359.292,"frameId":"1172.1"}],"endTime":13961359.356},
{"type":"Program","data":{},"startTime":13961363.636,"children":[],"endTime":13961363.668},

A lot of requests with and without / at the end ? :o

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck all day literally... :(

Answer (score 0):

So status is that I still do not know what caused this problem, but I guess it had something to do with the localisation, I solved my issue by using a different controller and routes for the editing part, and leave the translation of the route to the other.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a folder in your public folder with the same name as your route, that could cause this.

Change the name of 'public/used' or the name of your route. Whichever is easier.